# Slow boot ElementaryOS 5.1.7 after install Snapd

Tags: system-installation, boot, system, user, secure-boot

My boot is too slow - 1min 1.778s. Im beginner in linux and i have old PC but enough for elementary i think... I noticed that after install snapd boot is slower. Can i delete this service and how ??

systemd-analyze blame

```
     41.149s dev-sda1.device
     26.252s snapd.service
     22.230s pantheon-parental-controls.service
     20.470s networkd-dispatcher.service
     20.368s dev-loop1.device
     20.366s dev-loop0.device
     20.159s dev-loop2.device
     19.976s udisks2.service
     19.954s dev-loop3.device
     19.857s dev-loop4.device
     14.568s ModemManager.service
     11.599s NetworkManager.service
     10.908s thermald.service
     10.859s pppd-dns.service
     10.716s kerneloops.service
      8.856s systemd-logind.service
      8.309s accounts-daemon.service
      8.280s apparmor.service
      7.276s lightdm.service
      7.275s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      6.856s systemd-journal-flush.service
      6.453s systemd-udevd.service
      5.508s wpa_supplicant.service
      4.831s rsyslog.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove:

```
apt remove --purge -y snapd 
rm -rf /root/snap /snap /var/lib/snapd /var/snap
```